# ASP.NET error page does not work remotly

Tags: asp.net

I have problem with ASP.NET error page within my ASP.NET MVC application. When I browser to my application and exception happen then I just get this:

> Runtime Error Description: An
>   application error occurred on the
>   server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent
>   the details of the application error
>   from being viewed remotely (for
>   security reasons). It could, however,
>   be viewed by browsers running on the
>   local server machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this
>   specific error message to be viewable
>   on remote machines, please create a
>    tag within a
>   "web.config" configuration file
>   located in the root directory of the
>   current web application. This
>    tag should then have
>   its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

But I have  in my Web.config so seems that this is not a solution, so what's the correct solution to have entire stack trace displayed on the page? I don't really want to implement at this point my own error page.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on health monitoring, you can get more of the details of this message.  Also, are you using IIS?  Which version?  Anything below IIS 7 needs a special setup.